# Rails - can't make database migration on Heroku for app using Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, database-migration

My application uses Devise authentication gem.

When i do

```
rake db:migrate
```

locally, everything is going well, but when I do this on Heroku:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app myappname
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Devise::Encryptors::Base

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have no Idea what could go wrong.

Comment: What does `rake db:migrate --trace` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run into the same issue because I implemented a custom encryptor. Since version 2.1 of devise custom encryptors have been extracted to a separate gem. To get it working do the following.

Add the devise-encryptable gem to your `Gemfile`.

`gem 'devise-encryptable'`

Subclass from Devise::Encryptable::Encryptors::Base instead of Devise::Encryptors::Base.

```
# lib/devise/encryptors/md5.rb
require 'digest/md5'

module Devise
  module Encryptable
    module Encryptors
      class Md5 < Base
        def self.digest(password, stretches, salt, pepper)
          str = [password, salt].flatten.compact.join
          Digest::MD5.hexdigest(str)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I updated the [how-to page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-custom-encryptor) of devise as well. I hope this solves your problem.